# Passing an argument through an if statement in Scheme is resulting in an error

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm just getting started with scheme, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
(let ((fn (car last-elem))
      (output(if (> (length last-elem) 1) ;or = needed?
                (cdr last-elem)
                ( '() ))))

(cond ((equal? fn 'dim) (dim output))
      ((equal? fn 'print) (print output))
```

This code is supposed to generate the statement and then pass it through to print, my testing case its Hello, World!

Print right now (it will have more stuff later so I do need a new function) is just this:

```
(define (print args)
    (display(args))
    (newline)
```

This errors out with:

application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: ("Hello, World!")
  arguments...: [none]
  context...:

I think I'm on the write track, because the output I am hoping to get is there in the "given." But I want that to just print.

I know there are a few other questions on SO about this error, but none of their solutions helped me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are `dim` and `last-elem`? there are missing procedures in the question

Comment: dim is currently not used, last-elem is the last element in a list. The overall objective of the program is to be a silly-basic interpreter, it takes a program and executes it. The program in question is just to print "Hello, World!" That is why I'm pretty sure everything else is working, because I can see it there in the given. I don't know much about scheme though, so I'm running on mostly guesswork here.

Comment: Start by removing the unused parts then, otherwise the code won't even compile. You can't refer to a variable or a procedure that is not currently in scope.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot return just posted the comment. I edited it, also, there is a significant amount of code missing, but these are the parts causing the problem. The code obviously compiles.

Comment: Please post the _minimum_ part of the code that's giving you trouble and that _compiles_ by itself, with no dependencies (or, post the dependencies). If we can't run the code in the question, it's unlikely that we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the `print` procedure has an extra and incorrect set of parentheses, it should look like this:

```
(define (print args)
  (display args)
  (newline))
```

When you get the "application: not a procedure; expected a procedure" error, it means that you're using parentheses wrong, in Scheme `(f)` means that you're trying to *apply* `f` as a no-arguments procedure, if `f` is not a procedure then you get the error.

Comment: >(display args) This fixed it, what is the difference?

Comment: See the last paragraph

Comment: No problem, it was my pleasure!